# Arduino debounce button with delay

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm having a bit of trouble with my Arduino when I try and use long wires to a switch.

If I use a shorter wire I have no problems, but as soon as they are extended, things start playing up.

What I'm trying to do is, when I press a button I would like it to output to a pin, stay on for 2 seconds, then turn off regardless whether the button is still pressed or not.

The code I use at the moment that does work with short wires is:

```
// constants won't change. They're used here
// to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  10;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(2000); // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

I've been reading on forums that using debounce may solve this problem. However I'm new to Arduino and not sure how to implement this.

I used [the Arduino button tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button) and used a 10k pull down resistor as stated. Is there any way I can allow, either with code or with a resistor / cap, to trigger via a switch that has a wire length of <2m?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Explain the actual behavior vs the expected one

Answer (score 0):

Wire length is not going to be an issue here. You either have a wiring fault or your code doesn't match your expected behaviour. (You didn't mention what the actual behaviour is right now.)

Additional debouncing of the switch won't be necessary since after you detect a button press, you are ignoring its state for some time. That is what software debouncing typically is.

> stay on for 2 seconds, then turn off regardless whether the button is still pressed or not.

Right now the output will not turn off until you release the button. The reason for this is that after you write it low, you immediately check the button again and write the output high if it's still pressed. You either need to put a delay below

> digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

or be a little fancier and make sure the button is released before you allow another press.